# Checkboxlist inside Repeater inside DataGrid issue (C#)

Tags: c#, datagrid, repeater, checkboxlist

I know this is a bit odd, but there's a good reason for it.

I have a DataGrid, and inside the Datagrid there is a Repeater, and inside the Repeater, there is a CheckBoxList

```
<asp:DataGrid ID="dg" runat="server">
   <Columns>
      <asp:TemplateColumn>
          <ItemTemplate>
              <asp:Repeater ID="rep" runat="server">
                 <ItemTemplate>
                     <asp:CheckBoxList ID="cbl" runat="server" DataTextField="Name" DataValueField="ID"></asp:CheckBoxList>                                
                 </ItemTemplate>
              </asp:Repeater>
          </ItemTemplate>
      </asp:TemplateColumn>
   </Columns>
</Components:ExtendedDataGrid>
```

This is resulting in a fairly bizarre issue.  Clicking on the labels in the first repeater item works fine.  However, in the second repeater item, the labels get off.

- If you click the 2nd item in the 2nd group, the 1st item in the 2nd group is selected.
- If you click the 1st item in the 3rd group, the last item in the 2nd group is selected.
- If you click the 3rd item in the 3rd group, the 1st item in the 3rd group is selected.

So, it skips 1 in the second group, skips 2 in the 3rd, etc.  Very weird.

When I view the source, I can see that the "for" attributes on the labels are, indeed, wrong.

Any ideas at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok... I finally got back to this and figured it out.  I actually had a hidden field next to the checkboxlist that I didn't mention.  For some reason, when I took that out, everything else started working just fine.